# React set multiple inputs in an array of a state Object

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I'm not sure if it's possible to do, in my React app, I have a `<form>` with the following input fields:

```
<TextField />
<TextField />
<TextField />
```

and I have a state

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState({
    firstName:"", 
    lastName:"",
    colors:[]
})
```

I know how to set a single field using ES6 Spread like `setInfo(...info, firstName:e.target.value)`, but that doesn't seem to work with an array in Object.

Currently, if I want to set the colors, I go:

```
<TextField onChange={addColor1}/>
<TextField onChange={addColor2}/>
<TextField onChange={addColor3}/>
```

and then I create an `array colors = [color1, color2, color 3]`, and lastly I `setInfo({...info, colors:colors})

But I want to know if there's a way to set the color array without having to write repeated functions like `addColor1`, `addColor2` ...

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to do that ?? I'm just curious...

To answer your question, you could use 'push'

Comment: Actually pushing to an array in state will mutate it. You can spread the array just as you are currently spreading the object. `setInfo({...info, colors:[...info.colors, colorToAdd]})`

Comment: @NoxinDVictus say, in the future, the app grows, and people want to add more colors they like, then there should be a button to add more input field and allow people to input more colors, the solution in my code is never an ideal way I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good question. Let's see if we can construct one.

```
  const addColor = color => e => {
    const oldColors = info.colors
    // do whatever to create a new colors
    // based on oldColors and color, ex.
    const colors = [...oldColors, color]
    
    setInfo({ ...info, colors: colors })
  }
```

You should be able to use it this way.

```
  <TextField onChange={addColor('red')} />
```

This is the idea, `color => e` is something i think you might find it useful. But i don't know exactly how you will pull off with an array structure. In the end i don't think your way would work, but just keep trying or search something called widget `MultiSelect` or `Checkboxes` or something. They are more used for an array of items.

Comment: as i said, you need to see what's implemented in the `TextField`, maybe you don't need `e`, then you can drop it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely use a single function to handle the change events for all form-controls.

It's better to change the colours' data structure to an object or a map but if you want to use an array here's an example:

[image: Edit eloquent-pateu-lu2xo]

```
export default function App() {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    colors: new Array(3).fill("")
  });

  const handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    setInfo((prevInfo) => {
      if (name === "firstName" || name === "lastName") {
        return { ...prevInfo, [name]: value };
      }

      // to get 0/1/2 from color0/color1/color2
      const colorIndex = +name[name.length - 1];

      return {
        ...prevInfo,
        colors: Object.assign([...prevInfo.colors], { [colorIndex]: value })
      };
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={info.firstName}
        name="firstName"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={info.lastName}
        name="lastName"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <div>
        {info.colors.map((color, index) => {
          return (
            <textarea
              key={index}
              value={color}
              name={`color${index}`}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
      {JSON.stringify(info)}
    </div>
  );
}
```